# How to create a trigger to populate a table from another table in a different database

Tags: sql-server, database

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a dynamic trigger where if a table from database 1 has a new record inputed. if it falls in the category of data that I need for database 2, it automatically populates the table in database 2 without me needed to manually update.

Right now I am going into the table in database 1 sorting for the category I need and copying the data I need into the table in database 2.

I tried to make this process easier by doing a select query for the columns that I need from database 1 to database 2, which works fine however it overwrites what I have already and I have to basically recreate everytime.

So after all that rambling I guess exactly what I need to know. Is there a way to create a trigger that if a new line item is inputed in database 1 with the tag matching the type of material I need to transfer to database 2. Also on top of that I only need to transfer 2 columns from database 1 to database 2.

I would try to post a sample code, however I have no idea where to start on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unclear about the logic in your selection but if you want to save a copy of what was just inserted into table1 into a table (table2) on another database, using a trigger, you can try this:

```
create trigger trig1 on dbo.table1 
after insert as 
insert into database2.dbo.table2 (col1,col2,col3) values    (inserted.col1,           inserted.col2)`
```

Comment: Thanks Yes this works great, however it doesn't give me my sort to select only the right kind of material that I need. ie.. I don't need line items about the work gloves ordered or stuff along those lines. I just need actual production material. And whoever created this database before I got here, made one table for every kind of anything that we order, without a filtering system. So I will create my own column for categorizing, but I need my trigger query to incorporate only finding the material I need. Sorry for the confusion, to many things in my head trying to get on paper, you know

Comment: You need either a join or a where clause to filter out only the rows you need. What you are asking for is that you need good clothes - what should you get? You need to be a lot more specific on how you filter out rows that should be inserted through the trigger or how you want to select the rows.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into Service Broker messaging.  We use it quite a bit and it works quite well.  You can send messages to the other database with the data that needs to be inserted and allow the second database to do all the work.  This will alleviate the worries about the second database being offline or causing an error which rolls back into your trigger.  If the second database is unavailable the messages will queue up in your database until it can send them.  This isn't the easiest thing to set up but is a way to keep the two databases from being so closely tied together.
[Service Broker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Service Broker messaging is a very elegant, powerful solution but may be a bit much for a beginner and considering the time it would take to set up would be too much for today's busy work environment.

Comment: Agreed.  Troubleshooting issues with cross database inserts isn't fun either.  Especially when the insert in the trigger is blocked by something on another database.  I am definitely not suggesting that this should be an immediate answer but worth looking at especially if there is a chance these to databases could be on separate servers.  This is not something I would jump into lightly.  Worth the reading though.

Comment: The database are located on the same server. I will study into Service Broker though as it would seem to give me if anything a redundant reminder or a savior for any missed information from the trigger.

Comment: If you use the trigger to actually update the second table I would not use Service Broker in conjunction.  No need.  If the trigger doesn't insert the data then you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AFTER INSERT Trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [FirstDB].[dbo].[YourTrigger]
   ON  [FirstDB].[dbo].[Table] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [OtherDB].[dbo].[Table] SELECT (values...)
END
```

I recommend you consider non-trigger alternatives as well though.  Cross-DB triggers could be risky (what if the other db is offline, etc.)

Comment: Yes that is a very good point, my fear is that the old database was set up so poorly and unorganized that I would miss a lot of new material without having an auto trigger, but yes having a redundant option would be huge. Thanks